# Do Ionic + Cordova work on websites built by AngularJS 1.x?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a website built by mean-stack: MongoDB, `AngularJS 1.x`, ExpressJS and NodeJS.

My question is whether I could wrap the website to mobile apps by Ionic + Cordova. My concern is whether Ionic + Cordova supports `Angular 1.x`?

Comment: If I were you, my concern would be whether you can run MEAN stack inside Cordova. And the answer is probably not (and I wouldn't do it for production). Thats just not the way to go about it . The super-simple way to make an "app" from it would be to load your website when the app opens. But does that meet your requirement, and how would the app be different than having a bookmark on the phone?

Comment: Is it because of `AngularJS 1.x` that the mean-stack does not work with Cordova? It would be a huge limitation of Ionic + Cordova, no?

Comment: I know the super-simple way you mentioned, I am looking for another way in this question...

Comment: Ionic 1, which is almost the legacy version of Ionic is based on Angular 1. The later version of Ionic is based on Angular4. The way I would do it is create a web API for your current MEAN application and use latest version of Ionic to consume that.

Comment: The way you suggested is good. But i want to make sure one thing: it is still possible to make `Ionic 1 + Cordova + AngularJS 1.x` work, right?

Comment: Yes. You will be developing the mobile app with those 3 technologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic 1.x uses AngularJS (i.e. Angular 1.x).